# Issue with Deploying my PHP application on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my Php application on Heroku through Github which is a requirement of my web engineering module at university but I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: Application not supported by this buildpack!
 !     
 !     The 'heroku/php' buildpack is set on this application, but was
 !     unable to detect a PHP codebase.
 !     
 !     A PHP app on Heroku requires a 'composer.json' at the root of
 !     the directory structure, or an 'index.php' for legacy behavior.
 !     
 !     If you are trying to deploy a PHP application, ensure that one
 !     of these files is present at the top level directory.
 !     
 !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
 !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
 !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
 !     
 !     For more information, refer to the following documentation:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

[image]

[image: content of the view folder]

My application is contained in two folders at the moment.
The second image displays the content of the view folder.

My guess is that architecture is not adequate for the deployment on heroku but I have no idea on how to solve this issue. I tried to rename the homepage to index.php but of course it is not a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do what it told you. You can add a `composer.json` to define dependencies. `index.php` is required at `/`. So maybe you should add one and redirect to `/view/homepage.php`?

Maybe you want a `Procfile` at `/` too like:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 view/
```

If you do so, `/index.php` is not necessary but make sure `/view/index.php` is there.

Comment: Check the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#prepare-the-app)([source code for the docs.](https://github.com/heroku/php-getting-started/)).

Comment: It worked!!!! thank you very much ycao, very very much appreciated!! Next step will be the database but for today this is a huge step :-)